How to text wrap (or soft-wrap) in Problems panel In Pycharm/IntelliJ?
I am trying to text wrap (or soft-wrap) in the Problems panel. While the Alt+Z is working for me in both the console and in the editor, it's not working in the Problems panel. Here's a pic for your reference.


There is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-50409. Please vote for it and follow for updates.
